# Xcode 4.3 installation error

Tags: xcode

When I click on a project on Xcode it loads the old xcode, but I just installed the new XCode 4.3. How can I configure my Mac to load the new Xcode instead of the old Xcode?

I know that I had installed correctly the new Xcode 4.3 because I can still load it just by clicking on the icon of Xcode 4.3, but my old Xcode still somewhere of the hard drive causing it to boot when you click directly on any file of a project on Xcode.

It is very useful to load the Xcode directly from the projects itself vs. loading first the Xcode, then looking for the right project to open.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's no such thing as Xcode 4.3.

Comment: This should belong on either apple.se.com or su.com

Comment: @BoltClock: No longer true. :-) Updating for newness.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4.3 [is now fully self-contained][1] in the app bundle that is installed in the /Applications folder. The 4.2 installation in the /Developer folder is left intact. The first time you run Xcode 4.3, you'll be prompted to remove old tools.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete Xcode from /Developer/Applications, and drag the Xcode 4.3 app to /Applications. It should work fine after that.